# How to draw stencil ref value

Tags: directx, fragment-shader, stencil

hi i am currently implementing UI screen that shows Depth Complexity of scene, 
so that we can figure out how many time each pixels work for same pixels.

for this i need to render stencil ref value.
i successed to READ stencil ref value of each pixels using staging texture.
but i couldn't figure out how to pass this data to pixel shader, so that i can render 'Depth complexity'.

brief code that i have tried now.

```
//initializing Depth Stencil buffer-----------------------------------

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC ds_desc;
    ds_desc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    ds_desc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    ds_desc.MipLevels = 1;
    ds_desc.ArraySize = 1;
    ds_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS;
    ds_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    ds_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    ds_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    ds_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    ds_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    ds_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    Create DepthStencil Texture ...

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsv_desc;
    dsv_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    dsv_desc.Flags = 0;
    dsv_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    dsv_desc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    Create DepthStencilView

    DX_DContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, rtv.GetAddressOf(), dsView.Get());

// process to create SRV--------------------------------------------------------
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_X24_TYPELESS_G8_UINT;
    desc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    desc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    Create StagingTexture2D...

DX_DContext->CopyResource(copyTex->Get(), graphic->DepthStencilBuffer());

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
    srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_X24_TYPELESS_G8_UINT;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    Create SRV for binding to pixel shader...

//
```

and i bind this srv into this pixel shader
and just always showing BLACK

```
Texture2D<float4> uiTexture : register(t0);

float4 main(PS_INPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    int2 idx = int2(0, 0);
    return uiTexture[idx];

}
```

any advice or alternative would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Texture2D<uint2> uiTexture : register(t0);`

Texture2D should be defined like this. and then uiTexture[idx].y will be stencil ref value.

and probably another value(uiTexture[idx].x) will be depth.
cheers